# On Visual Studio for Mac, when working with a MVC Framework, is there a way to not have to rebuilt everytime I make a change in the html

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I think my question gave all the context, but here is the build button.

I feel like there is definitely an obvious answer to this, but I can't find anything online or in VS's help manual.

Comment: If you are using ASP.NET Core you could try using [dotnet watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch)? Visual Studio for Mac does not have built-in support for hot reloading HTML pages.